# How to know what got a thread killed in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, java-11, confluence, tomcat9

In our confluence server (tomcat 9 based), we added interruptThreshold to 30mins to kill long running threads (usually these are stuck threads).

However, interrupts for certain threads are not succesful (and it is okay, as it's mentioned in documentation that it doesn't work in all cases), but these specific threads gets killed after 8 hours.

These specific threads are related to a custom plugin and our developers say they don't have such 8 hours setting anywhere and I couldn't find anything in tomcat or in confluence.

We will be able to replicate the stuck threads, but how to findout what's killing them after 8 hours?

Answer (score 1):

Such actions on Tomcat should be logged in the {CONFLUENCE_HOME}/{DATA_FOLDER}/logs folder, please find these logs files and look for this operation/timestamp.

If for some reason, logs are not fully reflected, you can set it as described in
https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-logging-181535215.html.

Also, you can control loggng in -X... Java / Tomcat statements when running start.bin/start.sh.